# convert this multi dimensional 3 level deep array to 2 level deep or 1 level deep array so can be easily accessible) in PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

How to make it more simple (means I do not want a multi dimensional array)i want to just simply access one row at a time . convert this multi dimensional 3 level deep array  to 2 level deep or 1 level deep array so can be easily accessible) in PHP

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => 22" 120g Honey Comb
                [sku] => Sonia-22
                [price] => 100
                [qty] => 74
                [image] => 
                [description] => 
                [attribute_value_id] => null
                [brand_id] => null
                [category_id] => null
                [store_id] => 3
                [availability] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [name] => Side Fringe2
                [sku] => FrSideHH#1B-WU
                [price] => 150
                [qty] => 195
                [image] =>
                [description] => 
                [attribute_value_id] => null
                [brand_id] => ["1"]
                [category_id] => ["5"]
                [store_id] => 3
                [availability] => 1
            )

        )
   )
```

Comment: the easiest way i have found to access 'name' value  is this because converting this 3 level deep multidimensional array to 2 level or 1 level deep is a lengthy process. Solution is this `for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){ for($j=0;$j<=$count;$j++){ if(!empty($products[$i][$j]['name'])){echo $products[$i][$j]['name'];}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your varDump is showing by the looks of it one parent array with many children, so the simplest way of tackling it would be below:

```
foreach($mainArray[0] as $child){
       foreach($child as $row){
          echo $row['name'] . "\n";
      }
}
```

If you wanted to use the names as a separate array for use elsewhere then do:

```
array_push($myNamesArray, $row['name']);
```

Place it within the child foreach loop above.

This gives you a single dimensional array which you can loop on elsewhere in your code.

Comment: the easiest way i have found is this because converting this 3 level deep multidimensional array to 2 level or 1 level deep is a lengthy process. Solution is this     `for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
                                 for($j=0;$j<=$count;$j++){ 
                                    if(!empty($products[$i][$j]['name'])){echo $products[$i][$j]['name'];}`